# Fortnite on Nintendo Switch - Multiple Epic accounts?

Tags: nintendo-switch, fortnite-battle-royale, nintendo-account

I'm finding conflicting into on this in web searches, and hoping to get a definitive answer.

If multiple people in a household want to play **Fortnite** on **Switch**, what's the best way to register so that each individual has their own **separate identity**?

From having played Fortnite in the past on macOS, I know that one's experience level dictates who you're grouped with in online play (players of a similar skill level). One would also not want to lose access to any in-game collectibles purchased with V-bucks.

I don't want to screw this up. How should I go about this?

**Current configuration details:**

There are already multiple user profiles on the Switch, but just one Nintendo Account for purchasing games on the eShop. Also, I don't know if an Epic account can have multiple profiles associated with it, or if those can be linked with the individual profiles on the Switch.

**Ideal configuration:**

| Switch users | Fortnite player profiles | Epic account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 (linked to Nintendo Account) | Jane Doe | family Epic account |
| User 2 | John Doe | family Epic account |
| User 3 | Jamie Doe | family Epic account |
| User 4 | Me | my preexisting Epic account |

**Individual Epic accounts would also be alright:**

| Switch users | Fortnite player profiles | Epic account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 (linked to Nintendo Account) | Jane Doe | Jane's Epic account |
| User 2 | John Doe | John's Epic account |
| User 3 | Jamie Doe | Jamie's Epic account |
| User 4 | Me | my preexisting Epic account |

Managing multiple users through a single account is easier for me, but if there is long-term value in creating an account for each individual (they retain their purchases and *manage their own* in the future), I am okay with that. That raises another question though: Can a user be forked off into a new Epic account in the future?

**What I see when attempting to play on Switch:**

[image]

When actually trying to play Fortnite on Switch for the first time it asks if the player wants to "**link an account**".

[image]

The next screen shows an anxiety-inducing "**are you sure? You *will not* be able to link your account in the future if you proceed without signing up or logging in.**"

[image]

It sounds like something to carefully consider before committing to a path forward. Can somebody please explain how this works?

**Related findings (with conflicting info):**

[Fortnite PSA: Connect your Epic Account. You won't be able to do it again.](https://www.reddit.com/r/nintendo/comments/8qkzf7/fortnite_psa_connect_your_epic_account_you_wont/)

[Is it impossible to link an Epic Games account after you start?](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/211139-fortnite/76475050)

Comment: You could try asking Epic support how it works? But they haven't been super useful for me in the past.

Comment: @Rup Thanks. I ended up taking your advice. They were helpful. :-)

Answer (score 2):

<sup>I contacted [Epic Support](https://www.epicgames.com/help/en-US/contact-us) directly and got assistance via chat. The representative was helpful, and I will relay what was relayed to me. None of this is legal advice. I will do my best to explain what was explained to me, and maybe it can help others.</sup>

---

Individual Epic accounts is the way to go - one Epic Account corresponding to each Switch 'user' profile.

Each Switch user profile has Nintendo Customer Support ID, that allows Epic Games to uniquely identify the account.

| Switch users | Fortnite data on Epic Account (1 per person) |
| --- | --- |
| User 1 (linked to Nintendo Account) | Jane Doe's Epic Account |
| User 2 | John Doe's Epic Account |
| User 3 | Jamie Doe's Epic Account |
| User 4 | My preexisting Epic Account |

And yes, you can think of it as: Epic users can be "forked" (my wording, not theirs) into their own separate accounts. But from what I gathered, it is probably *more accurate* to say that each person creates an Epic Account for playing, but they don't necessarily get full privileges associated with that Epic Account by default. Further privileges require associating an email address with the account or parental authorization (more on that in a moment).

If the first thing the Epic Accounts will be used for is playing Fortnite on Switch, it makes sense to set them up individually and separately from one another from the beginning. But you could also start with existing Epic Accounts.

A person needs to be at least 13 years old to own a standard Epic Account. However, Epic offers a feature called [Cabined Accounts](https://www.epicgames.com/site/en-US/cabinedaccounts) that allow players under 13 to play Fortnite with some limitations on chat, in-game purchases, etc. And parents can manage those limitations.

Once you've got the Epic Account, log in with it on the Switch and...

> All Fortnite progress will be kept to the Epic Games account and not
> in console account, so if you wish to unlink your Switch account, the
> progress will retain to Epic.

I don't believe this is the case if you choose *not* to link your account before starting to play. That's the important thing to pay attention to with account linkage.

I asked (considering my configuration): **is buying V-bucks is best done through Epic's website?**

The support rep went on to say they "would recommend **buying V-Bucks through the console**, this is to avoid possible error in the future." and then went on to explain:

> Epic Games account is different to Nintendo Switch account. Currently,
> only PlayStation, Xbox, PC, Mac, and Android support the Fortnite
> Shared Wallet. This means your V-Bucks balance may change depending on
> what platform you’re on.
>
> Let me give you an example:     1,000 V-Bucks purchased on PC
>
> - PlayStation, Xbox, PC, and Android will display 1,000 V-Bucks available.
> - Nintendo Switch will display 0 V-Bucks available.
>
> So if you wish to purchase a V-Bucks, you must purchase it in Switch
> account rather than in Epic Website.

**Regarding purchases and multiple accounts/users:**

> **Q:** Since each Switch 'user' will have a different Epic account
> associated with it, but only "User 1" has a Nintendo Account linked to
> it, how do V-bucks purchases work for the other users?
>
> **A:** V-bucks transactions need to be done separately, one-by-one from
> each Switch 'user' profile.

What this looks like exactly, I will soon find out. It seems it will involve accessing the Nintendo eShop with a single Nintendo Account from multiple Switch 'user' profiles.

Finally, here is the [Store FAQ link](https://www.epicgames.com/site/en-US/epic-games-store-faq).

---

**Update: Setting up Cabined accounts**

Cabined accounts are given a default Display Name, which can be changed after a parent/guardian confirms the association of their email address with the Epic Account. There is a step for the parent to click a link in a confirmation email and confirm their age using [SuperAwesome](https://www.superawesome.com) (you can view their privacy policy [here](https://www.superawesome.com/age-verification-privacy-policy/)) - this can be completed using several offered methods, including [Yoti](https://www.yoti.com) facial age estimation ([biometric data not retained](https://www.yoti.com/privacy/app/)) and credit card info (no purchases required). An age rating limit for games/content can be set. Once these steps are completed, while logged into the Cabined Epic Account the Display Name can be changed in Account Settings. It can be changed later, but only once every two weeks. Other personal details can be entered too, but are private and optional.